# Проверка правильного ввода пароля в поле TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Задаю время показа текста:

```
private int i = 3000; // 3 секунды
```

На таймере:

```
if (i == 0) // показываю 3 секунды текст и прячу
{
  IncorrectPass.Text = "Неверный пароль!";
}
if (this.TextBox.Text == "12345")
{
  IncorrectPass.Text = "Пароль верен!";
}
  else
IncorrectPass.Visible = false;
```

На кнопку проверки:

```
IncorrectPass.Visible = true;
timer1.Start();
```

Как автоматически скрыть `IncorrectPass.Text` после 3 секунд? 
И так по новой, показать на 3 секунды текст и спрятать!

Comment: что используется winforms? wpf? asp.net?

Comment: @user2455111, `winforms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "12345")
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label1.Text = "Правильный пароль";
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Неправильный пароль";
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Invoke((Action)(() => { label1.Visible = false; }));
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274857/c-sharp-show-a-text-in-a-label-for-a-particular-time) похожий вопрос. Используют таймеры.  И еще я думаю возможно лучше будет использовать MaskedTextBox для этой цели

Comment: Ну так отметь решением